Help, I've broken two kernels in ubuntu 24.04 by using sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic
when newest kernels were installed I lost the ability to play files with rhythmbox.
I was able to revert back to previous kernel and regained usage of rhythmbox. after another upgraded kernel came out it too broke rhythmbox.
I can still revert back to the working kernel but if another upgraded kernel comes out my working kernel will fall off the recovery list so I wanted to delete the non working kernels to make room.
I asked google how to remove the kernels and found this command to remove the kernels. sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic.
Now i am unable to boot these kernels and they are still listed as installed.
I found the mainline app and tried to use it to remove the bad kernels but too many errors and fails.How can I repair or fully remove the broken kernels.
after running this script "sudo apt purge $(apt-cache pkgnames |fgrep 5.8.0-53)" this is the results, not sure if I have completely formated it properly, I'm new to this.
    Reading database ... 244305 files and directories currently
    installed.)

    Removing linux-image-6.5.0-45-generic (6.5.0-45.45~22.04.1) ...
    /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:

    update-initramfs:

    Deleting /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic/etc/kernel/postrm.d/
    zz-update-grub:Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'/usr/sbin/grub-
    mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: If:not found run-parts: /etc/
    kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127

    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-45-generic (--
    remove): installed linux-image-6.5.0-45-generic package post-
    removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1 
    dpkg:too many errors, stopping Errors were encountered while
    processing:linux-image-6.5.0-45-generic

    Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

    stanley@stanley-OptiPlex-7020:~$

Just a thought, I have a complete backup using deja-dup could I do a partial recovery of just a couple of subdirectories that contain the necessary files to restore the kernel builds or is this a road to ruin.

Your working kernel should not fall off GRUB (recovery list) while it's the running kernel, so there should be no need for any of these gymnastics.

I don't see a rhythmbox bug report in Launchpad matching your description. Has the rhythmbox problem been reported?

I would be surprised if a kernel update broke rhythmbox. And if it's really 5.8 kernel, that's pretty old. How did you get it in 24.04? Is that really what you're using? Bottom line, this whole thing doesn't make much sense.

dear organic marble, yes the computer was loaded with 24.04. the kernel 5.8 I showed as an example of the syntax used with the script i executed. It was the example I found when looking for the way to remove kernels. The real working kernel is 6.2.0-060200. The kernels I F****d up were 6.5.0-45-generic and 6.8.0-40-generic. I believe the reason rhythmbox might be having trouble is I'm running tweek to give me greater control of the fonts. I am trying to read a 30 inch monitor from 15 feet away, the standard included fonts just weren't cutting it,

You literally said "using sudo apt-get purge linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic". Why would you say that when you actually used a different command? What else in the post is not what you actually did? Oh, I see you mentioned that kernel in another command you said you did, but presumably didn't! I'm out.

back up everything on your hard drives then format the hard drive and reinstall ubuntu. Thanks to everyone who gave info on how to correct my mistake, however none was successful. I've given up and started over from the beginning.

Please click the big gray check beside your answer to mark it as accepted.

A kernel release has many associated packages, and all installed ones should be purged to do what you want.  I use something like:
sudo apt purge $(apt-cache pkgnames |fgrep 5.8.0-53)

which will find many packages, and list the ones to purge for your confirmation.
There are other answers on cleaning up broken package issues, like those caused by deleting a file directly, but from your posting, that's not the case here.

Please add lengthy output to your original posting, there are better formatting options than in comments. The only thing left associated with the kernel packages might be the /lib/modules/ directory -- claimed not empty, so not deleted. Some leftover module probably, so that directory may be "sudo rm -rf /lib/modules/" to get rid of it.  Again, if you had manually deleted any kernel files, the package manager will complain and quit -- couldn't tell from the comments which file, but you can just make an empty dir/file (mkdir or touch) and the package manager purge should  then work.

Yes as long as I never accept another kernel update from ubuntu I can keep the last working kernel on the setback list.
